# Corner design in css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have this image and I am wondering how to get this design. How to design the highlighted borders in CSS and html.

[image]

Comment: You need to look for **ribbon** effect. You will find plenty of solutions

Comment: Specially, look at http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a couple of pseudo elements and create triangles with their borders then position them absolutely to sit where you want.

[More information on pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

**EXAMPLE**

```css
div{
    background:#999;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
div::before,div::after{
    content:"";
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
}
div::before{
    border-bottom:20px solid #333;
 border-right:20px solid transparent;
    top:0;
}
div::after{
    border-top:20px solid #333;
 border-right:20px solid transparent;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. For future reference, when posting questions here, you should include sample code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes Sir, i will post