# create ribbon with css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have sidebar menu finally created. now I need create ribbon on selected item like show image (red) (I need really gray color ribbon). But I don't want use image background and use only css class. So dynamically I can remove class name and add to another item.

I have a `you_are_here` class which selected item in that I want see ribbon. Is it possible to do that?

[image]

```
 <ul class="outer">
  <li>
    <p class="top">My Account</p>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="#">My Account Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Demographics</p>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="#">Addresses</a></li>
      <li class="you_are_here"><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>


.outer P, .inner P { padding: 0.25em 0.75em; }
.outer>LI>P { font-weight: bolder; margin: 1em 0 0 0.5em;  }
.outer>LI>P.top {
    margin: 0; background: #eee; background: linear-gradient(0deg, #DCDCDC, #F6F6F6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(219,215,219,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(219,215,219,1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(219,215,219,1);
     border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
     border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
     font-size: 150%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:120%;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;   
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(219,215,219,1);   
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(219,215,219,1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(219,215,219,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #dbd7db;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(219,215,219,1);
    -ms-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.outer { padding: 0;width: 90%;font-family: "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
UL.outer, UL.inner { list-style: none; padding: 0 }
.outer LI { padding: 0; border: none; }
.inner LI { padding: 0.25em 1.75em; border: 1px solid white;font-family: "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
.inner LI:hover { border: 1px solid #ddd; background: #eee; }
LI.you_are_here { background: #ddd; border: 1px solid #bbb; }
LI.you_are_here A { color: black; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bolder; }
```

### [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/0jbmq7ug/1/)

something like this

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Corner design in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803400/corner-design-in-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will have to be adapted to your needs, but something using pseudo elements would make this possible:

```css
.box{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 15px #222;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:gray;
  }

.active{
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:-5%;
  height:30px;
  width:105%;
  background:tomato;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  }
.active:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:16px;
  top:5px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border-top:2px dashed red;
  border-bottom:2px dashed red;
  }
.active:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:-10px;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  top:5px;
  background:tomato;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  transform:rotate(45deg);  
  }
.active a{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:30px;
  }
.active a:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-15px;
  left:6px;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background:darkred;;
  transform:rotate(45deg);  
  z-index:-2;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">

<div class="active">
  <a href="#">some text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**note**

the transform property will require prefixes as well.

Comment: I added your code in jsfiddle it is not creating left corner ribbon turn. http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/opc48675/

Comment: @James123: the snippet info would make the css invalid: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/opc48675/1/

Answer (score 1):

it's real with CSS3.

maybe like this:) 
but you need to customize.

html:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.one > div {
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  background: #0fadc0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: -45%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.main > div {
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: 40px;
}
.bk {
  background: #1199a9;
  position: absolute;
  width: 8%;
  top: 12px;
}
.bk.l {
  left: 0;
}
.bk.r {
  right: 0;
}
.skew {
  position: absolute;
  background: #0c7582;
  width: 3%;
  top: 6px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.skew.l {
  left: 5%;
  transform: skew(00deg, 20deg);
}
.skew.r {
  right: 5%;
  transform: skew(00deg, -20deg);
}
.bk.l > div {
  left: -30px;
}
.bk.r > div {
  right: -30px;
}
.arrow {
  height: 25px !important;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.arrow.top {
  top: 0px;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #1199a9;
}
.arrow.bottom {
  top: 25px;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #1199a9;
}
.r .bottom {
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #1199a9;
  border-right: none;
}
.r .top {
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #1199a9;
  border-right: none;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .skew.l {
    left: 5%;
    transform: skew(00deg, 25deg);
  }
  .skew.r {
    right: 5%;
    transform: skew(00deg, -25deg);
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 680px) {
  .skew.l {
    left: 5%;
    transform: skew(00deg, 30deg);
  }
  .skew.r {
    right: 5%;
    transform: skew(00deg, -30deg);
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 460px) {
  .skew.l {
    left: 5%;
    transform: skew(00deg, 40deg);
  }
  .skew.r {
    right: 5%;
    transform: skew(00deg, -40deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- RIBBON 1 -->
<div class="container one">
  <div class="bk l">
    <div class="arrow top"></div>
    <div class="arrow bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="skew l"></div>

  <div class="main">
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="skew r"></div>

  <div class="bk r">
    <div class="arrow top"></div>
    <div class="arrow bottom"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5pu4rqr8/

this is a pure copy/paste from [@willpaige's CodePen](http://codepen.io/willpaige/details/zwxBK/)

Comment: Thanks to credit the author, this is a pure copy/paste from [@willpaige's CodePen](http://codepen.io/willpaige/details/zwxBK/)